# Datatable select producing incorrect concatenation of columns

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

I have a problem when selecting data from a datatable in c#. I am populating a combo box with this. Column 1 is repeating with different descriptions. This is the code I am using.

```
var comboItems = this.coreDataSet.Tables["TimesheetDataTable"].AsEnumerable()
                          .Select(row => row.Field<string>("column 1") + " (" + row.Field<string>("description") + ")")
                          .Distinct()
                          .ToList();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement shows exactly what I would expect.

[image: Table content]

Code to fill the combobox with EntityFramework, instead of DataTables:

```
using (var timesheetDb = new TimeSheetContext())
{
    var comboItems = timesheetDb.TimeSheets.Select(row => row.Column1 + " (" + row.Description + ")").Distinct().ToList();

    foreach (var item in comboItems)
    {
        TestCombo.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

[image: Combobox]

What is your data? And what is your aim calling .Distinct()?

Comment: My aim was to have only one entry for each distinct column 1. I know I must do a group by on that column but I couldn't get that working

Comment: The data is a set of project codes with a matching description as separate fields. I am trying to get the description of each distinct project code in brackets so users know what project it is.

Comment: My idea was to execute the mysql query "Select concat(projectcode, ' (', description, ')') from table group by projectcode" in an entity framework